# Why does margin-top not work to get the yellow box down?

Tags: html, css, margin

Don't mind the commented out lines. I'm experimenting with the box model, but can't seem to figure out why I can't use margin-top to drop the yellow box a bit down? I can use margin-left to get it to move to the right, so that seem weird to me... Thanks.

I'd like to understand why this happens :)

```css
.largebox {
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #00f;
    //padding-left: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    //border: 2px solid black;
}

.box1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    //display: inline;
    //float: left;
    //margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="largebox">
        <div class="box1"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: next time do a better search, the exact same title was already questioned here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *happens* due to [**`margin collapsing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) - so a `border`, `padding` to the *parent element* or `inline` content (any `inline` element) will switch off margin collapsing.

See demo below:

```css
.largebox {
  width: 800px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #00f;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid; /*ADDED THIS*/

}
.box1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="largebox">
  <div class="box1"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block;` in `box1`

```css
.largebox {
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #00f;
    //padding-left: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    //border: 2px solid black;
}

.box1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    //display: inline;
    //float: left;
    //margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="largebox">
        <div class="box1"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain to me why having the default display doesnt work?

Comment: @Veen `inline-block` actually tells the browser to calculate the dimensions of the div after its placed and then those calculations are applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `position:absolute;` in `.box1` like this:

```
.box1{
    position:absolute;
}
```